# Regex: Removing everything inside () using .NET

Tags: regex, f#

I am using System.Text.RegularExpressions

I have a string like this:

```
 let foo = "XXX XXX (YYY YYY YYY)"
```

I want it to be "XXX XXX" after applying a regex like so:

```
let bar = Regex.Replace(foo, pattern,"")
```

I have tried:

```
let pattern = @"\(\w*\)"

let pattern = @"\(\*\)"
```

Can someone give me some guidance?
Thanks

Comment: Must it be done with regular expressions? What should happen if there are more characters *after* the parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis , as they are special regex characters used to capture groups.

`\(.*\)` will match the parenthesis and everything inside them.

As Eric pointed out , if you also want to match the white-space before the parenthesis, you should use `\s*\(.*\)`.

Comment: But I believe he'll still end up with "XXX XXX " (extra trailing space)?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
var foo = "XXX XXX (YYY YYY YYY)";
var pattern = @"\s*\([^\)]+\)";
string bar = Regex.Replace(foo, pattern, "");
```

After regex replace, `bar` is:

"XXXX XXX"